# Routes not working in modular structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've got these structure for my mean app, but by now let's focus on express routing, here is my structure:

```
├── node_modules
├── src
│   ├── client
│   │   └── ... //Frontend things managed by angular (like views, etc...)
│   └── server
│       ├── modules //By module i mean an entity
|       |   ├── auth
|       |   |   ├── users.model.js
|       |   |   ├── signin.controller.js
|       |   |   └── index.js
|       |   └── ...
|       ├── config
|       └── ...
|
├── package.json
└── server.js
```

Here's my **server.js**

```
/* main module entry point */
'use strict';

var Express = require('express');

var env = require('./src/server/components/config/env');
var db = require('./src/server/components/config/db');

var app = module.exports = Express();

app.use( 'usuario', require( './src/server/modules/auth' )() );

app.listen(env.port, function () {

    console.log('Listening to port ' + env.port);

});
```

Here's my **auth/index.js**

```
 module.exports = function () {

    var express = require('express'),
        router = express.Router(),
        signin = require('./signin.controller');

    router.route( '/iniciar-sesion' )
        .get( signin.get )
        .post( signin.post );

    return router;

 };
```

And here's my **auth/signin.controller.js**

```
module.exports = function() {

    function  get( req, res ) {

        console.log('Sign In');

    }

    function  post( req, res ) {

        console.log('Sign In');

    }

    return {
        get: get,
        post: post
    }

}();
```

When i access to http://localhost:3000/usuario/iniciar-sesion i get a message like this:

> Cannot GET /usuario/iniciar-sesion

and nothing on the console, also if i use a () at the end of the **auth/index.js** func the server doesn't start:

```
module.exports = function () {

    var express = require('express'),
        router = express.Router(),
        signin = require('./signin.controller');

    router.route( '/iniciar-sesion' )
        .get( signin.get )
        .post( signin.post );

    return router;

 }();
```

> debug('dispatching %s %s', req.method, req.url);
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'method' of undefined

What am i missing?

Comment: The line of code that reads `app.use( 'usuario', require( './src/server/modules/auth' )() );` - that url points to the auth folder, have you tried pointing directly to the individual .js files instead? Also, make sure to put a / before your route's name, like so: `app.use( 'usuario', require( './src/server/modules/auth/index' )() );`

Comment: oh, thanks, i didn't know that!, but it's not necessary to call it like: `'./src/server/modules/auth/index'`, this worked: `app.use( '/usuario', require( './src/server/modules/auth' )() );`

Comment: Great, so it's solved? You might want to answer your own question :)

Comment: Mmm yes it's solved, but i would also like to know why using the `()` at the end of the func **auth/index.js** gives an error, maybe you should answer it so i accept your answer:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the issue here lies within the fact that the route you supply to the `app.use()` method needs to be prepended with a "/" - it's necessary for separating the domain name from the route parts of your URL.

Like this:

```
app.use( '/usuario', require( './src/server/modules/auth' )() );
```

Furthermore, the reason why this code fails:

```
module.exports = function () {

    var express = require('express'),
        router = express.Router(),
        signin = require('./signin.controller');

    router.route( '/iniciar-sesion' )
        .get( signin.get )
        .post( signin.post );

    return router;

 }();
```

Is because it's a syntax error. If you want a function to be self invoking, you need to enclose it in parentheses, like this:

```
module.exports = (function () {

    var express = require('express'),
        router = express.Router(),
        signin = require('./signin.controller');

    router.route( '/iniciar-sesion' )
        .get( signin.get )
        .post( signin.post );

    return router;

 })();
```

It should also be noted that if you used a self invoking function, you'd need to remove the parentheses from the `require()` method in your `app.use()` invocation, like so:

```
app.use( 'usuario', require( './src/server/modules/auth' ) );
```

Glad you found your solution :)

Comment: Thnks, could you please explain me whats the difference between self invoking function and the other —what are they called?

Comment: The difference lies in when and how the function is invoked. Self invoking functions invoke themselves, so they can retain their anonymity **and** return a value in one fell swoop. The parentheses are just the syntax for achieving this, anything else is just a standard function which requires different syntax.

Comment: Hmmm, so in this case there's no pain using any of them right?

Comment: Either works great :) I wouldnt use the self invoking anonymous function for simplicity's sake though